# Yaml frontmatter not parsing as documented

Tags: php, yaml

I have yaml frontmatter installed in a php/Laravel project, but I cannot get it to work as documentend.

I made a testfile test.html:

```
--- 
title: Example 
--- 
Lorem ipsum.
```

Then I try to parse with yaml:

```
$document = YamlFrontMatter::parse(file_get_contents('test.html'));

dd($document->title);
```

The result:

```
Spatie\YamlFrontMatter\Document {#280 ▼
  #matter: []
  #body: "--- title: Example --- Lorem ipsum."
}
```

While matter should be:

```
['title' => 'Example']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Kind regards

Hubert

Comment: Frontmatter is usually used in Markdown files, have you tried using `test.md` instead of `test.html`?

Comment: Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `dd($document->title);` should output _only_ `Example`, are you certain that is the correct file you're running? `dd($document)` would output your "The result"

Comment: You are correct. Actually the code was dd($document)

Answer (score 1):

First your **test.html** file move to **resources** folder now follow this code

```
$document = YamlFrontMatter::parseFile(resource_path('test.html'));

dd($document->title);
```

I hope you this solution is work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the 3 dashes had one space in front `---`  and that made the parser to no recognize the properties, when the space was removed all worked back again.